# How to write condition on Filter String in code Reports Winforms devexpress?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, report

I designed a report form and map fields with columns of tables from dataset. Now I need to set condition, so I used `FilterString`. Inside report form DetailReport, I wrote code like this:

`DetailReport.FilterString = "[InvoiceNumber] = " + temp;`

Now I need this same code (`FilterString`) for whole form that is top left of form `Report Task` some properties are available in that Data Source there we add dataset, Data Member, Data Adapter then `FilterString` is available.

Now I am able to add `FilterString` in Designer but I need to add `FilterString` in code ?? 
I Tried this one but not working 
`FilterString= "[InvoiceNumber] = " + temp"`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seggest you set the report `FilterString` property when you call for your `XtraReport` (for example : when you click on the print button of your form). Here is an code example :

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Create a report instance.
    XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();

    // Some code like setting the report datasource

    // Specify the report's filter string.
    report.FilterString = "[InvoiceNumber] = myValue";

    // Show the report's print preview.
    pt.ShowPreviewDialog();
}
```

This code was taken from the DevExpress online documentation article : [XtraReportBase.FilterString Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReportBase_FilterStringtopic)

Comment: Yeah now its working fine thank you. Till me trying in report form and  event on it.

Answer (score 1):

Once you set the filter for the report, in the for you need to have it do:

```
 public string p = "";

....

  using (XtraReport_yourreport x = new XtraReport_yourreport ())
            {
                p = x.FilterString;

            }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering, Sorry I don't know where to use this code ?      I wrote this code `DetailReport.FilterString = "[InvoiceNumber] = " + temp;` on BeforePrint Event so that when i click report button on form   it run this line before report shows.

Comment: I get unique number from form using constructor and store it on invisible textbox and assign temp = textbox.